# In-app Purchase using server

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

so I need to use in-app Purchase with my server, like in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1 example 1-3. Is there any tutorial how to send the data to the server? I've found this http://www.phpriot.com/articles/verifying-app-store-receipts-php-curl but I don't know what I should do in the client thing.

Thanks.

Comment: What client "thing"? If you want high quality answers, make your question of the same quality.

Comment: @Eli Are you going to use a php server for verification of receipt & sending the content to iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the workflow will be:

- User presses "buy something"
- App (!) goes to App Store and does In-App purchase
- App (!) sends to server a message "user THIS ID has bought THIS THING"
- server (using something like that curl script) verifies, that purchase is OK
- server updates DB or something.

The similar thing is drawn on a PHP site. So, what is the question again?